# How to programatically enable sharding for a database and then shard the collection using node.js mongodb driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following nodejs script that currently creates a few trial databases and then creates a collection and inserts a sample entry into the collections. Now I would like to enable sharding for the database and then shard the collection based on the hashed `id` field. How can I do that?

The `host` and `port` in the code point to where mongos is running.

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var name = "sampledb";

function start() {
    for (var i=4;i<20;++i) {
        var dbname = name + i;
        mongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname, function(err, db) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Error connecting to db");
                process.exit(0);
            }
            db.createCollection("messages", function(err_, result_) {
                if (err_) {
                    console.log("Error while creating collection");
                    process.exit(0);
                }
                db.collection("messages").insert({"id":"<random id>"}, {w:0}, function(err, result) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("Could not insert document");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Successfully inserted document");
                    }
                });
                //now shard the collections created
            });
        });
    }
}

start();
```

I could not get hold of proper documentation for my question, can someone please help me out...Thanks.

Comment: Changing the database setup programatically is a bad idea in the first place and every DBA with the slightest idea of what he is doing would limit the user for data retrieval to exactly that role and permissions. There are by far more implications on Sharding than visible at first glance.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg thanks, it's not a production setup, but a test setup that I want to verify with.

Comment: Ok, let me put it differently: wether to shard a collection is not at the developers discretion, but at the admins. In order to set up a sharded collection (let's say for integration testing) you should do it by hand.